# "echo"-ing xml data from sql database via php script

Tags: php, sql, xml

I would like to be able to echo/get the "raw" xml data which stored as a **longtext** in SQL database via PHP script.

This is the **sample database**:

[image]

the **xml file** I have stored in the SQL database is:
[image]

and my current **php script** is:
[image]

current output i have currently is:
[image]

**The output however is not what i expected**

I would expect to have something like:
[image]

Could you please help to point out what is wrong with the code?
because aside from the XML value i'm able to *echo* a normal text

Comment: please no pictures of code thank you. Post code and errors and data as text only.

Comment: @hikari just replace TestParameter line by ":TestParameter:".htmlentities($row['TestParameter']).';'."<br/>";

Comment: If you are sharing information to iOS and Android web services then you should use JSON encode before sending

Comment: Thank youuuu very mucchh..@Mangesh Sathe ! 
That really answer my questions ♡＾▽＾♡

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any text that starts with `<` followed by letter. Use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function to output any HTML code as plain text.

To output HTML data with `<` encoded to `&lt;`

Comment: Nice （＾ω＾）!!!
Thats exactly what i need the htmlentities()
Thank youuu very muchhh @Justinas